# How to use selenium to search a webpage for a key in a dictionary, fill in the answer field with the corresponding value? (python, selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I want to automatically answer a security question on a webpage. The question is chosen randomly from 6 questions. I have a dictionary whose keys and values correspond to the questions and answers respectively. I want to use selenium to search the webpage for the keys and if a key is found I want to enter in the answer field. Below is my failed attempt.

```
secuQA = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4, 'e':5, 'f':6}

# i want to loop through the keys in the secuQA and search the webpage for each of them 

# i think I will have to use: 
browser.find_element_by_name(keys)


# if question contains a key in the dict, fill answer field w/ corresp value
ansElem = browser.find_element_by_id("secu_answ")
ansElem.click()
ansElem.send_keys(secuQA[key])
```

Edit: Below is the source for the part of the webpage I thought was relevant.

```
<form class="form_login" id="vbsecques" name="vbsecques" method="post" encType="multipart/form-data"  action="fillquestions.aspx">
        <label for="secu_ques" class="">Question 1 of 3:</label>
        <div id="secu_ques" class="">
            <div id="secu_ques" class="">In what city did you meet your spouse/significant other?</div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <label for="secu_answ" class="">Answer</label>
        <input type="password" id="secu_answ" name="secu_answ" class="form-control ehd_sec_ques" placeholder="Answer" autocomplete="off" required autofocus />
        <input type="hidden" id="lid" name="lid" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" id="aflag" name="aflag" value="submit" />
        <br />

        <br />
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block ehd_sec_ques" type="submit">Submit</button>
        <br />
    </form>
```

Comment: Could you provide the page or the page source? Screenshots might also help.

Comment: I've added source code to my post.

Comment: It's still not clear what you want to do. What's the relationship between the html code you provided and the keys that you have? Does it mean that the answer for question 1, in the example, will be always 'a'?

Comment: I want to loop through the keys and see if any of the keys are included in the html text. For example, "spouse" could be one of the keys and if it is in the html, I want to enter the value corresponding to "spouse" in the answer field. Yes the answer for 1 is always 'a'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must find the question element.

```
q_element = driver.find_element_by_id("secu_ques")
question_strings = q_element.text.split(" ")#get a list of words from the question sentence

for key in secuQA:
    if key in question_strings:
        ans = secuQA[key]
        break
```

Naturally the keys you're using must be unique for being able to identify correctly the corresponding answer. 
Let me know if this helps.